# C++ return statement not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, visual-c++, return

I have the following C++ code:

```
return lineNum >= startLineNum
&& lineNum <= startLineNum + lines.size() - 1;
```

Here, `lineNum` is an `int`, `startLineNum` is an `int`, `lines` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, and `lines.size()` is of type `size_t`.

When `lineNum` is 2, `startLineNum` is 0, and `lines.size()` is 0, the code returns `true` even though `false` was expected. These values were the values displayed in the debugger.

Even after adding parentheses where possible:

```
return ((lineNum >= startLineNum)
&& (lineNum <= (startLineNum + lines.size() - 1)));
```

the code still incorrectly returns `true`.

When I refactor the code into this form:

```
int start = startLineNum;
int end = startLineNum + lines.size() - 1;
return lineNum >= start && lineNum <= end;
```

it now returns `false` as expected.

What is going on here? I have never come across this kind of strangeness before.

Comment: How do you tell the values?  Are you looking at the values displayed in the debugger, or have you printed them out beforehand?

Comment: What are the *types* of the variables? And please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with unsigned arithmetics. lines.size() is of size_t type, what type is startLineNum ?

Comment: Incidentally, I would find your test easier to read if a) you used a half-open interval; b) you keep the comparisons in the same direction.  So `startLineNum <= lineNum && lineNum < startLineNum + lines.size()`

Comment: Not too bad an error someone can make... but it's unlikely this will help any visitor in the future.

Comment: @marcinj Well done!  That is the problem.

Comment: The values are displayed in the debugger. I will edit my question so that it will specify the types of the values.

Comment: Now you have your answer, just remember to do explicit cast in the general case. `lineNum <= (startLineNum + (int) lines.size() - 1))`. Anyway here, the output of (startLineNum + (int) lines.size() - 1)) is expected to be an int, so you don't risk any loss of performance since there will be a cast anyway.

Comment: _I have never come across this kind of strangeness before_ You can also attempt to make a loop counting back `for (size_t n = 10; n >= 0; --n)`

Comment: @KillzoneKid: In that case, the *slide operator* can be useful, as can the  `for (size_t n = 10; n <= 10; --n) ` trick.

Comment: @Bathsheba wouldn't this be UB when size_t overflows?

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Nope. Only signed types have overflow UB. Unsigned types must wrap.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`lines.size()` is more than likely an *unsigned type*. (If `lines` is a `std::vector` for example it's *certainly* `unsigned`.)

So due to the rules of *argument promotion*, and the fact that the terms in

```
startLineNum + lines.size() - 1;
```

are *grouped* from left to right, they are all converted to `unsigned` types.

This means that `0 + 0 - 1` is `std::numeric_limits<decltype(lines.size())>::max()` - a large number indeed, and `lineNum` is most likely less than it.

**The rule of thumb: never use a negative when working with unsigned types, unless you really know what you're doing.**

In your case, restate the problem to

```
lineNum < startLineNum + lines.size()
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that

```
lineNum <= startLineNum + lines.size() - 1;
```

is all unsigned types. `linenum` is 2, the other two are 0, and 0-1 in unsigned arithmetic is something VERY large (if 4 byte something above 4 billion).

Do instead

```
lineNum + 1 <= startLineNum + lines.size();
```

and all should be fine.

Comment: Or even better: `lineNum < startLineNum + lines.size()`.

Comment: Incidentally, I think it's *much* more likely that `startLineNum` and `lineNum` are of type `int`, and the integer literal `1` is *definitely* type `int`.

Comment: True, good catch. Though slightly less instructive, some people might think it only works for -1.

Comment: My guess would be startLineNum and lineNum are of type `std::size_t`, and of course `1` is of type `int`, but that doesn't mean the difference is signed...

Comment: Still, `lines.size()`is unsigned, and so is then the sum and the difference on the RHS.